# Unified interface to MArray and MVector

Tags: arrays, haskell, vector

How would you make a single interface to various implementations of mutable arrays and vectors, while keeping it pragmatic? I.e. with:

- performance comparable to direct use of arrays/vectors (without abstraction)
- minimum code duplication

Something like this:

```hs
-- (s)torage (k)ey (v)alue (m)onad
class (Monad m) => Storage s k v m where 
    empty :: k -> v -> m (s k v)
    alter :: (v -> v) -> k -> s k v -> m ()
    fold  :: (a -> v -> a) -> a -> s k v -> m a

main :: IO ()
main = do
    _a <-    empty 100 False :: IO   (IOUArray Int Bool)
    _b <-    empty 100 42    :: IO   (VUM.MVector RealWorld Int)
    let _c = empty 100 False :: ST s (STUArray   s Int Bool)
    let _d = empty 100 42    :: ST s (VUM.MVector s Int)
    return ()
```

The implementation for MArray can be something like this (seems working):

```hs
instance (Monad m, MArray s v m, Ix k, Num k) => Storage s k v m where
    empty   k v = A.newArray (0, k - 1) v
    alter f k s = A.readArray s k >>= A.writeArray s k . f
    fold  f a s = foldl' f a <$> A.getElems s
```

Here's a broken implementation for MVectors:

```hs
-- doesn't work
instance (PrimMonad m, MVector s v, Unbox v) => Storage s k v m where
    empty   k v = VUM.replicate k v
    alter f k s = VUM.modify s f k
    fold  f a s = VU.foldl' f a <$> VU.freeze s
```

Question:

- how would you implement an instance for MVector or refactor this code to make it possible to have an abstraction for both, arrays and vectors?

Imports and extensions:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses,
             RankNTypes #-}
module UnifiedArray where

import           Control.Monad.Primitive     (PrimMonad, PrimState)
import           Control.Monad.ST            (RealWorld, ST, runST)
import           Data.Array.IO               (IOUArray)
import           Data.Array.MArray           (Ix, MArray)
import qualified Data.Array.MArray           as A
import           Data.Array.ST               (STUArray)
import           Data.Foldable               (foldl')
import           Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable (MVector)
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed         as VU
import           Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable (Unbox)
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as VUM
```

Runnable source code:
https://gist.github.com/oshyshko/6fae4f859b8f8434af6d3f1eb3cad98e

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @pedrofurla there are multiple errors ranging from duplicate instance declarations to type mismatches in MVector implementation. For convenience, I've added a link to the runnable source code at the end of the question.

Comment: AFAICS, you can't make this work. Your instances completely overlap, and even turning on extensions won't be enough since the overlap can not be resolved. There is no way, in Haskell to state "if type T is in class C, then use this instance C2 T, otherwise use this other instance C2 T". You can only try to list all the relevant types, one by one, perhaps copying the long list from hoogle.

Answer (score 3):

The `vector` types aren't parametric on the index type, so you can't shoehorn them into quite the same interface as the `array` ones which are.

But first a more general issue: instances of the form

```
instance constraints => ClassName p q r
```

only really make sense for one thing: to define a *class synonym*, i.e. a class that is basically the same as its superclasses<sup>†</sup>.

In all other situations, the instance should mention at least one concrete type constructor. In your case that should probably be the concrete array and vector types, respectively:

```
instance (m ~ IO, MArray IOArray e m, Ix k, Num k) => Storage IOArray k e m where
  ...
instance (m ~ IO, MArray IOUArray e m, Ix k, Num k) => Storage IOUArray k e m where
  ...
instance (m ~ ST, MArray STArray e m, Ix k, Num k) => Storage STArray k e m where
  ...
```

Yes, this means some code duplication, but it'll be basically just trivial “linking definitions”.

Now, to make it compatible with vectors, you need to avoid having `s` take an index-type parameter. That's possible because the `array` types always take the index as the first argument, i.e. you can use currying to hard-bake an extra variable into the instance declarations. Then you can retrieve that information again with in form of an associated type family:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies #-}

module Asd where

import           Control.Monad.Primitive     (PrimMonad)
import           Data.Array.IO               (IOUArray)
import           Data.Array.MArray           (MArray)
import qualified Data.Array.MArray           as A
import           Data.Foldable               (foldl')
import           Data.Kind                   (Type)
import qualified Data.Vector                 as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as G
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable         as M

class (Monad m) => Storage s v m where
    type IndexingKey s :: Type
    empty :: IndexingKey s -> v -> m (s v)
    alter :: (v -> v) -> IndexingKey s -> s v -> m ()
    fold  :: (a -> v -> a) -> a -> s v -> m a

instance (m ~ IO, MArray IOUArray v m, A.Ix k, Num k)
                  => Storage (IOUArray k) v m where
    type IndexingKey (IOUArray k) = k
    empty   k v = A.newArray (0, k - 1) v
    alter f k s = A.readArray s k >>= A.writeArray s k . f
    fold  f a s = foldl' f a <$> A.getElems s

instance (PrimMonad m, s~M.PrimState m, G.MVector M.MVector v)
             => Storage (M.MVector s) v m where
    type IndexingKey (V.MVector s) = Int
    empty   k v = M.replicate k v
    alter f k s = M.modify s f k
    fold  f a s = V.foldl' f a <$> V.freeze s
```

---

<sup>†</sup>This can, incidentally, also be done with

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
    
type ClassName p q r = constraints
```

Comment: I am getting an error in the "V.MVector e m where" part:
    • Expecting one more argument to ‘M.MVector’
      Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘M.MVector’ has kind ‘* -> * -> *’
Full code here https://gist.github.com/oshyshko/f3f7a323bc797bc7e3cfe507eecbbf50 Do you also get this error?

Comment: Yeah, the `PrimState` needs to be taken care for. See edit.